How to get " sign for string args in python argparse
I want to write a program in Python that gets args of unspecified number and type. I can do this with argparse as follows:
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('args', help='Help', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

But the problem with this code is that when I give it these args for example: "Hello" -s "5" 98.5 --file True, it gives me this output: ['Hello', '-s', '5', '98.5', '--file', 'True']. It converts all values ​​to strings and removes the " sign for values ​​that are strings. I need this output: ['"Hello"', '-s', '"5"', '98.5', '--file', 'True'], to join all the values ​​together and get exactly the same string as the input that user entered: '"Hello" -s "5" 98.5 --file True'
I tried to use shlex.join and shlex.quote, but this library doesn't always work correctly and if user has entered a number as a string, it can't be identified with this method, like the example above.
sys.argv works in a similar way and doesn't accept " signs.
If it's a method other than using argparse, tell me.

The quotes you are asking about are only used by the shell; they aren't passed to Python at all. If you want the string "Hello" and not Hello, you need something like myscript '"Hello"' ..., not myscript "Hello" .... That is to say, the "outer" quotes aren't part of the argument at all, only part of the shell code that produces the argument.

Look at the sys.argv to see the list of STRINGS that the shell gives you.  With REMAINDER argparse just takes what it gets, without any attempt to parse it.

How about loading a json string? From file or quoted shell line.  Parsing can be done in argparse with a type function or post parsing.

That's not a Python issue. That's a shell issue. Shell "removes" quotes before passing it to Python. You have two options:
./script.py '"Hello"' -s '"5"' 98.5 --file True

or
./script.py \"Hello\" -s \"5\" 98.5 --file True

There's nothing you can do from the Python side.

Or just ./script.py '"Hello" -s "5" 98.5 --file True'

Is it possible to get args using another method and then pass them to python file so that this problem is solved and user doesn't need to use '" or /"? I don't know, for example, using a bat file or something else

Again, there's nothing you can do from the python side, quotes don't get to python at all.

@gthanop that whole thing would be treated as one (first) argument, wouldn't it?

I think yes and I posted the comment since initially I was thinking that the OP's intentions are not clear about needing separate arguments, but admitedly this was probably not enough concentration on their question from my side. Bad comment, my apologies.
